# Integrate Highcharts maps with react component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, highcharts, react-highcharts

I am trying to integrate [**highcarts**](https://www.highcharts.com/maps/demo/data-class-ranges) inside  the react component.

Here is my code for the react component

```
import * as Highcharts from 'highcharts/highmaps'
class RealTime extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
      $.getJSON(     'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/highcharts/highcharts@v7.0.0/samples/data/world-population-density.json',
        function(data) {
          $.each(data, function() {
            this.value = this.value < 1 ? 1 : this.value
          })
          Highcharts.mapChart('world_map', {
            chart: {
              map: 'custom/world'
            },
            title: {
              text: 'Fixed tooltip with HTML'
            },
            legend: {
              title: {
                text: 'Population density per km²',
                style: {
                  color:
                    (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.textColor) || 'black'
                }
              }
            },
            mapNavigation: {
              enabled: true,
              buttonOptions: {
                verticalAlign: 'bottom'
              }
            }, 
            series: [
              {
                data: data,
                mapData: Highcharts.maps['custom/world'],
                joinBy: ['iso-a3', 'code3'],
                name: 'Population density',
                states: {
                  hover: {
                    color: '#a4edba'
                  }
                }
              }
            ]
          })
        }
      )
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div className="map_bg" id="world_map"/>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

But the above code does not show either the map or any error in my react component . Can Anyone please help me
What i am missing here?

Thank you!!!

Comment: Using `$(document).ready(() => {` inside `componentDidMount()` makes no sense, i.e. `$.getJSON(...)` will never be called.

Comment: I tried that as well. But no luck

Comment: Sorry, your comment makes no sense. Maybe you should look into ready-made NPM modules, e.g. [react-highcharts](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-highcharts), instead...

Comment: But I can easily integrated this https://www.highcharts.com/demo/bar-basic. So what's the issue with the highmaps?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add and import the `word.js` script:

```
import Highcharts from "highcharts/highmaps";
import customWord from "./word.js";
```

Live demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/v0x5zx6q05

Also, I can recommend you to use `highcharts-react-official` wrapper: https://www.npmjs.com/package/highcharts-react-official

Comment: Awesome!!! How did you know that? I searched everywhere but nothing worked. Also what is the role of the `customWord` here

Comment: Hi @Profer, I am glad I could help. The `customWord` is unused variable, you can import the script in some other way.

Comment: OMG you have done marvellous job. THank you ones again. Is there any way so that I can implement dark theme https://www.highcharts.com/maps/demo/data-class-ranges/dark-unica

Comment: Yes, sure. You need to only set the theme options: https://codesandbox.io/s/v0x5zx6q05

Comment: *you can import the script in some other way* Which script do I need to import??

Comment: Is possible to implement bubble chart with the same API?

Comment: Hi @Sivaprakash D, To use `bubble` series type, you need to import and initialize `highcharts-more` module. Live example: https://codesandbox.io/s/highcharts-react-demo-i5w5l